# Netbeans + Codename One - Avoid importing packages or classes not suitable for CN1

Tags: netbeans, codenameone

I'm using Netbeans IDE. It's quite annoying and it's a cause of errors the import of Java packages and/or classes that are not provided by [Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com/). *(Codename One use its own implementation of a subset of Java8 and [it cannot support the full Java API](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/why-we-dont-support-the-full-java-api.html)).*

For example, sometimes Netbeans imports automatically wrong packages (such as "java.awt.BorderLayout" instead of "com.codename1.ui.layouts.BorderLayout"), other times it shows me methods and Javadocs that are not available in Codename One.

Is it possible to force Netbeans to show me only packages, classes, methods and javadocs that are supported by Codename One? It could be useful to avoid errors.

Comment: This is normal and is controlled by Netbeans IDE.

In my experience with CN1 plugin for Netbeans, if there is a method available in both CN1 and Java native code, I'm offered all in form of a drop-down/popup and CN1 import is the first on the list. I don't think there's a way to force import from a single location if other packages are available to your project...which is the case with all CN1 projects. Remember that CN1 extends most of these Java classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'd love to but unfortunately the only way NetBeans allows you to do that is if you build your own Java language package. That's what some other plugins like NBAndroid did AFAIK but when we implemented the plugin we didn't want to create something too complex.

If NetBeans supported a "bootclasspath" option for the JDK it would have solved everything. It does have support for plugging in an alternative JDK which can be a micro-profile but because we don't comply with the micro-profile spec I'm not sure if that will work.

Answer (score 1):

At times, NetBeans suggests to import more than one package from the drop-down list. When you check carefully before pressing ENTER this might avoid importing the wrong package.

I use NetBeans for quite a while with CN1 and faced the same problem at the beginning.